# Refreshing DataGridViewComboBox Items

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

Im trying to refresh the amount of days available in the ComboBox. This is a button that i created, where mindate and maxdate get their values from a DateTime Picker, and Dia is the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn but it doesnt work. Can anyone help me find the source of the problem and how to fix it. Or if you know another way of doing it, it would also help.
EDIT:The button i was talking is button3.

```
public partial class InserirViagens : Form
{
    private DateTime mindate;
    private DateTime maxdate;
    public InserirViagens()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = (Dados.agência.Viagens.Count + 1).ToString();
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
        dateTimePicker2.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
        mindate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        maxdate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int cod = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string des = textBox2.Text;
            double preço = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            DateTime inicio = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            DateTime fim = dateTimePicker2.Value;
            int contalinhas = (int)dataGridView1.RowCount-1;
            if (inicio<=fim)
            {
                Viagem v = new Viagem(cod, des, preço, inicio, fim);
                Dados.agência.Viagens.Add(cod, v);

                MessageBox.Show("Viagem Inserida com sucesso!\nContém " + contalinhas + " actividades.\n"+ Dados.dados.Viagens.Count + " Viagens existentes");
                this.Close();
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Data de fim inválida!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro de formatação!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);


        }









    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mindate = dateTimePicker1.Value;


    }

    private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        maxdate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       Dia.Items.Clear();
       while (mindate.DayOfYear < maxdate.DayOfYear)
       {
           Dia.Items.Add(mindate.Day + "/" + mindate.Month + "/" + mindate.Year);
           mindate.AddDays(1);
       }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: When i press this button, nothing happens just stays there. If you think it would help i can write the entire code of this form.

Comment: That would be helpful.

Comment: But when i change the value of the dates wasnt it supposed to update due to:   private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mindate = dateTimePicker1.Value;


    }

    private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        maxdate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    }?

Comment: See update/ solution in my post. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: I improved my code a little bit; see post and latest comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Dia.Items.Clear();
   while (mindate.DayOfYear < maxdate.DayOfYear)
   {
       Dia.Items.Add(mindate.Day + "/" + mindate.Month + "/" + mindate.Year);
       mindatee.AddDays(1);
   }
```

`mindatee.AddDays(1);` doesn't work.

**AddDays method information**

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the
>   value of this instance.

So it returns a new DateTime and doesn't change the old (in this case the mindate) value.

**Solution**

Save mindate.AddDays(1) in a temp variable and replace the current mindate with the temp datetime value.

```
   Dia.Items.Clear();
   while (mindatee.DayOfYear < maxdatee.DayOfYear)
   {
       Dia.Items.Add(mindate.Day + "/" + mindate.Month + "/" + mindate.Year);
       var tempDate = mindate.AddDays(1);
       mindate = tempDate;
   }
```

If you don't want to use a temp variable you can also do it in one line of code:

```
mindate = mindate.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: I improved my code a little bit, so you can implement it in one line of code. (Please set my question as solution/ as your accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime minDate = Convert.ToDateTime(mindate.Value);
        DateTime maxDate = Convert.ToDateTime(maxdate.Value);

        foreach ( DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbCol in dataGridView1.Columns) {
            cmbCol.Items.Clear();

            while (minDate.Day < maxDate.Day) {
                cmbCol.Items.Add($"{minDate.Day}/{minDate.Month}/{minDate.Year}");
               minDate= minDate.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```